# VB - Parameters for text box, nothing entered

Tags: vb.net

In my program i have a text box called "txtWallH" in which i want numbers between 2.4 and 6 to be entered, which i have done. (though If anyone could suggest a better way that'd be great)

So if this parameter is not met then a msgbox appears, and clears the field. I also want this to happen when nothing has been entered.

This is the code i have:

```
If TxtWallH.Text <= 2.39 Or TxtWallH.Text >= 6.01 Or TxtWallH.Text = "" Then
MsgBox("Please enter a value between 2.4m and 6.0m (wall height).")
TxtWallH.Clear()
End If
```

Thanks

Comment: why not check that the value is included within the range.  As it stands, your logic is slightly incorrect, in that one could input 2.391 and it would run.  So check on the value being >=2.40 or <6.00 in the if statement, and put an else condition with your messagebox and clearing.  Also you should look into using the IsNumeric() function to test that the value is actually a number, because one could type in letters or symbols into the textbox right now as well (unless there's already checks for that elsewhere)

Comment: sorry, slightly incorrect above, in that it should be >2.40 or <6.00, not >=2.40  noticed just after the five minute editing time was up.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if your Framework Version is lower than 4) to check whether anything has been entered. In addition, I propose using [OrElse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ea1sssb2.aspx) instead of Or. Also, I suggest to parse the value explicitly:

```
Dim value As Double
If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtWalH.Text) OrElse Not Double.TryParse(TxtWalH.Text, value) OrElse value < 2.4 OrElse value > 6.0 Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a value between 2.4m and 6.0m (wall height).")
    TxtWallH.Clear()
End If
```

Comment: you have an extra OrElse at the end

Comment: I'm not sure the check for blank is actually needed since tryparse is being used, as it would fail the cast, and thus the condition (at least i'm pretty sure that's how it would happen).

Answer (score 0):

```
If IsNumeric(TxtWallH.Text) And (TxtWallH.Text > 2.40 Or TxtWallH.Text < 6.00)  Then
'Processing goes here
Else
MsgBox("Please enter a value between 2.4m and 6.0m (wall height).")
TxtWallH.Clear()
End If
```

This will account for non numeric as well as blank input.  Feel free to change > and < to >= and <= if 2.40 and 6.00 are still valid inputs (it's not entirely clear from what was provided if they are or not...)

Answer (score 0):

A NumericUpDown control with a minimum value of 2.4 and a maximum value of 6 and an increment of .1 will automatically restrict the value, leaving you free to use it as you like.

You can set the increment however fine you want it. And the user can scroll to the value or type it in.

Comment: The obvious problem with this, is that tenths of a number may not be accurate enough (of course, it might be as well, in which case this is fine)

Comment: You can set the increment however fine you want it.  And the user can scroll to the value or type it in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
If Not (val(TxtWallH.Text) > 2.4 AND val(TxtWallH.Text) < 6.00) AND TxtWallH.Text <> "" Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a value between 2.4m and 6.0m (wall height).")
    TxtWallH.Clear()
End If
```

(val(TxtWallH.Text) > 2.4 AND val(TxtWallH.Text) < 6.00)
   
this line will check if the textbox's **VALUE** is **BETWEEN** 2.4 and 6.